# Django, how to use CreateView and UpdateView to add two records at the same time

Tags: django, forms, django-generic-views

I need a model with some FloatField feilds, each records of this table should be used with another one (first row indicates minimum and the second one determines maximum).
I like the values of these two rows be added or edited simultaneously by user.
I'm eager to know how to use django CreateView and UpdateView generic classes or any other tools for this purpose.
Please let me know your helpful comments.

Update:
this is a part of my codes:

```
#models.py
class DefinedInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bound = models.CharField(max_length=3) #takes 'min' or 'max'
    density = models.FloatField(default=0)
    weight =models.FloatField(default=0)
    ....


#views.py
class InfoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = DefinedInfo
    template_name = 'item_new.html'
    fields = ['density', 'weight' ...]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.bound = 'min'
        return super().form_valid(form)

class InfoUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = DefinedInfo
    fields = ['density', 'weight' ...]
    template_name = 'item_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.user == self.request.user


#Html template
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

 {% block content %}
<div>
<h5>Define new item</h5>
  <div>
 <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form|crispy }}
  <button" type="submit">Save </button> 
  <button type="reset" onclick="location.href={% url 'profile' %}" >Cancel</button>
</form>
</div>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

There is no problem to add or edit individual records, but I prefer to handle "min" and "max" related records at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As written now, your question doesn't describe a specific problem you're having. Please see how to write a [mcve] and also [ask]. You should show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Generic Class based Views are made to update/create/delet one single object of a Model at a time.
If you want to make some customizations, it might be clearer and **easier to write your own views**.

Making a UpdateModel(UpdateView) is confusing if it does modify two rows in the DB.

Comment: Then, discarding the Generic Class based Views, what is the best way for adding these two rows to DB simultaneously?